# Как посмотреть полный ответ, который приходит от сервера при использовании curl?

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, http, curl

Как посмотреть полный ответ, который приходит от сервера при использовании curl? Т.е мне нужно увидеть не только тело, а вообще весть респонс с заголовками и метаинформацией.
я использую следующую команду

```
curl -X 'POST' -d '{"param1":"test1","param2":"test3"}' 127.0.0.1:8080/kv
```

Как мне сделать так, чтоб curl выводил все мтаинформацию?

Если это невозможно, посоветуйте пожалуйста другой инструмент.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252851

Comment: либо просто `curl -D - http....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с опцией `-D файл` возвращённые заголовки будут записаны в указанный файл. если вместо пути к файлу указать `-`, то они будут записаны в *stdout*:

```
$ curl -D - http://google.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 13:14:32 GMT
Expires: Sat, 27 Mar 2021 13:14:32 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

ещё больше (скорее уже отладочной) информации (в том числе и **переданные** заголовки) можно получить с помощью опции `-v` (записана она будет в *stderr*):

```
$ curl -v http://google.com
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 5 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 5 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 6 ms for 1 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
*   Trying 64.233.165.102...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149991 ms for 3 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x559fd2bb1ed0)
* Connected to google.com (64.233.165.102) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.google.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 13:16:30 GMT
< Expires: Sat, 27 Mar 2021 13:16:30 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Server: gws
< Content-Length: 219
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
```